# access to camera via USB in web flutter app

Tags: flutter, web, package, camera

I make a web application using flutter and I have external camera connected via USB, any solution for access it

I tried USB_device package, but I don't know how can open the external camera and take a picture using it, and also tried camera web package but it didn't work for USB camera.